# Creating Resftul URI Paths?

Tags: java, spring, rest, uri

I am creating a very simple `restful` web application using `Spring MVC`.

It is a "dog treat" application that allows a kennel owner to keep track of the amount of treats that each dog has been given.

The main page is just a `table` with all dog names and number of treats.

There is also functionality for:

- adding a treat for a specific dog.
- A link in the table to see more details for each dog.

I am thinking of creating my URI paths as the following:

```
/treats =  table with all dogs and treats

/treats/add = add a treat to a specific dog

/treats/{dog} = specifc details for a certain dog
```

Am i getting this wrong? This is my first restful service and I would like to get the design correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that design isn't quite correct. The first URL path is correct. But to add a dog to a specific treat, the URL should be

```
/dogs = GET retrieves all dogs, POST create a new dog
/dogs/{dogId} = GET retrieves one specific dog, POST updates the entity, DELETE deletes the entity
/dogs/{dogId}/treats = GET retrieves all treats, POST to add a new treat
/dogs/{dogId}/treats/{threatId} = POST/DELETE updates/deletes an entity
```

More information can be found here: [Spring REST Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/)

Comment: Im not sure I explained correctly. I want to add a treat to a dog, i.e. a dog can have many treats, rather than a dog to a treat? Thanks

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood. Then it should be the other way round:

    /dogs - GET for all dogs
    /dogs/{dogId}/treats - POST to add a treat
    /dogs/{dogId}/treats/{treatId} - POST/DELETE to update/delete

Comment: Ok thanks, so when I click on a specifc Dog in the table to see more details, the path should still be /treats/{dogId} ? What about the URL to add a completely new dog? Surely it would not start with /treats ?

Comment: In the overview the URL should be _/dogs_ and the URL for a specific dog _/dogs/{dogId}_.

Comment: I guess you are mixing up the REST URL with the URLs in the browser location bar. For example the URL _/dogs_ means something different in the REST context with POST (to create a new entity) and GET (get all existing entites).

The browser URL might be complete different to the REST URLs.

Comment: I thought the URL in the browser was typically the same? Could you please update answer with the URL for 1. adding a treat to a dog and 2. adding a new completely new dog so that I can accept the answer. :)